# PDO MySQL accepting non-specific values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have 3 rows in my database with `id`s 1, 2 and 3.

I realized that if you create a statement like so:

```
 $prepare=$database->prepare("select * from brand where id=?");
 $prepare->execute($array);
 echo $prepare->rowCount();
```

It will give count to array values are are not the exact id but close using `;`. For example

The array value to count works with values that use `'row';`

```
1 = 1
2 = 1
3 = 1
4 = 0
5 = 0
1;2 = 1
3;4 = 1
4;2 = 0
```

Why do values like `1;2` or `3;4` work with the query?

Comment: Because the `;` is a valid character, and end of statement character but still valid.

Comment: ...which Gordon has explained in detail below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reasonable question.  This has to do with the fact that MySQL does implicit conversion of strings to numbers in a numeric context.  It does the conversion by looking at the leading numbers in the strings and converting it.

So, the expression:

```
where id = '1;2'
```

is interpreted as:

```
where id = 1
```

And there is a match.

This is particularly nefarious in a table where `id` might be `0` and you have:

```
where id = 'abc'
```

The string is silently converted to the integer 0 -- and there might be a match.